# Location of kernel.sysrq

Tags: settings

The kernel.sysrq setting seems to be often located at /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf, however, I do not see this file on my Arch system. Instead, there seems to be a file:

```
/usr/lib/sysctl.d/50-default.conf
```

Are these kernel settings kept in different places in different distributions? If so, where should I edit kernel.sysrq to make the changes permanent in an Arch system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file location can differ from distribution to distribution.

More important part of the question is where to make the changes. The files in `/usr` can be regarded "static" or "system-managed". Think of "do not edit". In this case, the file provides a *default* configuration.

You are meant to copy (relevant parts of) the file into the corresponding directory under `/etc` and do your changes there. `/etc` is for *user* configuration (or rather settings made by the administrator and applied "to all users").

Answer (score 3):

See the description of [`sysctl --system`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/sysctl.8.html):

> Load settings from all system configuration files. Files are
> read from directories in the following list in given order
> from top to bottom.  Once a file of a given filename is
> loaded, any file of the same name in subsequent directories is
> ignored.
>
> ```
> /etc/sysctl.d/*.conf
> /run/sysctl.d/*.conf
> /usr/local/lib/sysctl.d/*.conf
> /usr/lib/sysctl.d/*.conf
> /lib/sysctl.d/*.conf
> /etc/sysctl.conf
> ```

So `/usr/lib/sysctl.d/50-default.conf` is appropriate for distribution-provided defaults, and your own overrides should go in `/etc/sysctl.conf`, or if you want to override the whole file, `/etc/sysctl.d/50-default.conf`.

As a general rule, you should never modify anything under `/usr` (except under `/usr/local`). Many programs with configuration shipped under `/usr` or `/lib` support overrides in `/etc`.